# beginning web programming

Tags: language-agnostic

I've been programming in the classic way: read input, process data, print output, for 4+ decades. Web programming is not quite like that...

I've done some HTML and created some pages. But where do I get information about where to place things on the web, how to call/reference them, what permissions do my files need, how do I protect programs/code/data from being accessed any way except through my program, how do I unravel the meaning of server side, user side, sewercide (just kidding). Where can I find a simple example that helps clarify these web programming ideas?

Comment: Well, perhaps you can share with us your prior/current experience? E.g. which languages are you good at? It might 'guide' you towards the technology/platform/laugauge/database etc that are more comfortable for you to start with.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the Web is just like that:

1. Read input (on the browser)
2. Process data (on the server)
3. Print output (on the server, viewed by the browser)

Start with [the MSDN website](http://www.asp.net/get-started/) if you are Microsoft oriented.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is to first decide on a technology stack you'd like to use (e.g., ASP.NET MVC, Ruby on Rails, PHP/MySQL) and then get a book that guides you through building a simple web application.

For instance, the canonical Ruby on Rails book is [Agile Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails).  It's got a great walkthrough that teaches you the framework while building an online book store.

With this method you're learning by actually building something hands-on.  You can always page fault in background information from resources like Wikipedia and w3schools if the book skips some fundamental concepts that you're missing.